# How to get the progress of tweenmax

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I'm using tweenMax to tween a sprite, basicaly rotate it. Is it possible to copy the tween value at some instant and feed it for another tween ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'onUpdate' function of tweenMax to get the current value..